# WAMP - localhost error

Tags: wamp

I recently reinstalled WAMP. I keep getting this error:

> 404 Not Found  
>  Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Comment: Could you elaborate your question more? Version of WAMP, Windows OS version,etc. will also add more information.

Comment: What happens when you type in: http://127.0.0.1 in a browser? Do you have multiple DBs installed and running, in the same copy of Windows?

Comment: same thing. requested url / not found. no, i don't have multiple databases

Comment: I too had  the same problem, but the problem was with the port  assigned to apache.IIS was already using the port 80,I have fixed it by changing  to 443 by editing apache config file.[link] (http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wamp-server-not-working).Please refer the link for more info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hit start, type `services.msc`, scroll down and look for `wampmysqld` and `wampapache`. Make sure both are listed and started. If not, do the following:

- If they are not present, click the Wampserver icon, select the service (Apache for wampapache and MySQL for wampmysqld), then Service, then Install Service
- If there are present but not started, try starting them. You can right click them, properties and click Start (and if you like set them to automatically start too to start when Windows does) or you can do the same as the previous step from the WampServer icon.

Check if apache is running on port 80 or 8080. Try this, to see the apache config and find the port:

`httpd -t`(you run this from a command prompt - start -> run -> cmd).

Note that if the wamp/apache/Apachex.x.xx/bin folder isn't in your PATH variable you will need to navigate to that folder in the command prompt or shift+right click inside the folder and select `Open Command Window Here`.