# 127.0.0.1 - not found

Tags: php, windows, wamp

I installed WAMP on Windows 8 and now I have on

```
http://127.0.0.1/
```

in browser I have:

```
Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.
```

Why? How can I find out where this address directs and how can i redirect this on C:/wamp/www?

Comment: Server was found, but server's root folder not. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#documentroot  Or you have something else (not yours Apache) running and listening port 80.

Comment: thanks, but in which file I can set documentroot for 127.0.0.1?

Comment: I do not use WAMP (prefer to setup Apache by myself). If is the default configuration or for the first host (if Apache 2.4 and above).

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1` means "connect to the web server running on the same computer as the browser". When a server is set up this way, it is only accessible at the server, and not from remote computers.  Misunderstanding this can result in hilarity since it will work at the server but not anywhere else. This setting has practical uses in testing and development, and tunnelling and reverse proxies can be used to get around the restriction to create websites from a mix of technologies.

Comment: Is the apache service running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you install Apache? Find that folder.

After you have that folder, find the `conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` file.
For example if Apache is installed in `C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17`,
then you're looking for this file:

```
C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Inside this file, find a section like this:

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost  
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
ServerName localhost  
ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common
```

Edit the `DocumentRoot` appropriately, restart the webserver, and try the page again.
Make sure there is a `index.html` file inside the directory you set in `DocumentRoot`.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that Apache server/service is started ?
 
Deactivate your firewall and try again
Hope it help

Comment: Yes, my others virtualhost working fine

Comment: in your httpd.conf file, wich port in configured ? search for 'listen' parameter

Answer (score 0):

Found previously on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12958511/wamp-localhost-error)

> Hit start, type services.msc, scroll down and look for wampmysqld and
>   wampapache. Make sure both are listed and started. If not, do the
>   following:
>
> If they are not present, click the Wampserver icon, select the service
>   (Apache for wampapache and MySQL for wampmysqld), then Service, then
>   Install Service
>
> If there are present but not started, try starting them. You can right
>   click them, properties and click Start (and if you like set them to
>   automatically start too to start when Windows does) or you can do the
>   same as the previous step from the WampServer icon.
>
> Check if apache is running on port 80 or 8080. Try this, to see the
>   apache config and find the port:
>
> httpd -t(you run this from a command prompt - start -> run -> cmd).
>
> Note that if the wamp/apache/Apachex.x.xx/bin folder isn't in your
>   PATH variable you will need to navigate to that folder in the command
>   prompt or shift+right click inside the folder and select Open Command
>   Window Here.